# Excluding a column from an operation without dropping it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change all values less than 5 in the following df with nan, but column B should be excluded from the operation without dropping it.

```
                    A   B   C   D
DateTime                
2016-03-03 05:45:00 1   2   3   4
2016-03-03 06:00:00 1   2   3   4
2016-03-03 06:15:00 1   2   3   4
2016-03-03 06:30:00 1   2   3   4
2016-03-03 06:45:00 1   2   3   4
```

desired result

```
                    A   B   C   D
DateTime                
2016-03-03 05:45:00 NaN 2   NaN NaN
2016-03-03 06:00:00 NaN 2   NaN NaN
2016-03-03 06:15:00 NaN 2   NaN NaN
2016-03-03 06:30:00 NaN 2   NaN NaN
2016-03-03 06:45:00 NaN 2   NaN NaN
```

I can take colum B out of the df then apply `df[df < 5] = np.nan` to the remaining df, then combine them again. Dropping column B before the operation can also be another approach. But I am looking for a more efficient way, one liner if posible.
Trying `df[df.columns.difference(['B']) < 5] = np.nan`, but it is not correct. Also `df[(df.B != 'Other') < 5] = np.nan` without a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df[df.columns.difference(['B'])]<5]=np.nan
```

Comment: for my data, this results consistent output when applied to different values and df.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a more sensible example:

```
                     A  B  C   D
DateTime                        
2016-03-03 05:45:00  1  2  3   4
2016-03-03 06:00:00  1  2  3  10
2016-03-03 06:15:00  1  2  6   4
2016-03-03 06:30:00  1  2  3   4
2016-03-03 06:45:00  1  2  6  10
```

---

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(['B'])] = df[df >= 5] 
df
                      A  B    C     D
DateTime                             
2016-03-03 05:45:00 NaN  2  NaN   NaN
2016-03-03 06:00:00 NaN  2  NaN  10.0
2016-03-03 06:15:00 NaN  2  6.0   NaN
2016-03-03 06:30:00 NaN  2  NaN   NaN
2016-03-03 06:45:00 NaN  2  6.0  10.0
```

This masks everything, but only assigns based on `loc`.

---

Another option is masking with `update`:

```
v = df[df >= 5]
v.update(df[['B']])

                      A    B    C     D
DateTime                               
2016-03-03 05:45:00 NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN
2016-03-03 06:00:00 NaN  2.0  NaN  10.0
2016-03-03 06:15:00 NaN  2.0  6.0   NaN
2016-03-03 06:30:00 NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN
2016-03-03 06:45:00 NaN  2.0  6.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Working from your code, you can do instead:

```
mask = (df.loc[:,df.columns.difference(['B']).tolist()] < 5).any()
df[mask[mask].index] = np.nan
```

Note that `df.columns.difference(['B'])` is a list of columns excluding `B`. So it doesn't make sense to see which are `< 5`. You firstly have to slice the dataframe with these columns to then check the consition. Finally you have to add `any` to check if there is at least a `True`.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is incorrect. Try it with some different values... this just blanket masks every column as long as it has a value < 5.

Comment: Here's an example: `{'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'B': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'C': [3, 3, 6, 3, 6],
 'D': [4, 10, 4, 4, 10]}` "6" and "10" should not be masked, but your code seems to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by slicing down the columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({l:range(10) for l in 'ABCDEFGH'})

dont_change=['B']

cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in dont_change]

df_sel = df.loc[:,cols] # select correct columns
df_sel[df_sel<5]=np.nan # modify
df[cols]=df_sel #reassign
```

Comment: It does not work here. My df has hundreds of columns. So, instead of choosing columns to include, I would rather assign a column to exclude.

Comment: My bad updated and working now. With improvement so you only need to choose columns to exclude in `dont_change` list

Answer (score 1):

You may using `mask`

```
df.mask(df.lt(5)).combine_first(df[['B']])

Out[258]: 
                     A    B   C   D
DateTime                           
2016-03-0305:45:00 NaN  2.0 NaN NaN
2016-03-0306:00:00 NaN  2.0 NaN NaN
2016-03-0306:15:00 NaN  2.0 NaN NaN
2016-03-0306:30:00 NaN  2.0 NaN NaN
2016-03-0306:45:00 NaN  2.0 NaN NaN
```